# Get Phoenix - Award WorkstationBIOS to recognize SATA hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, bios, sata

My bios is Phoenix - Award WorkstationBIOS.

I want to add a new HD to my system. The main HD is an IDE. The new one is a SATA hard drive. My motherboard has two SATA slots, so I think that it's supported. I plugged the SATA cord into the new hard drive and the other end to the motherboard, and plugged in a power cord. I have no idea what to do now, though. From what I've been able to gather from Google searches, I need the BIOS to recognize it, but boot with the IDE hard drive, and the SATA hard drive would just be extra storage.

How would I go about this? I can't find one decent guide to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed it correctly, it should be automatically picked up by the BIOS.

Simply go in to boot options and make sure that the "boot order" is set so it boots from the IDE hard drive first.

Sometimes there is a separate menu for reordering the hard drive order as the boot options may just say "hard drive".

After this, you should be good to go - simply format the drive when in your operating system and you should be able to use it.